# Visual Studio genera error en los archivos jquery al tratar de compilar

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de aps.net mvc c# el cual ya tengo dias de estar trabajando, pero de un momento a otro al tratar de compilar me genera error en todos los archivos jquery, tanto los que genera por defecto al crear el proyecto como lo que se han agregado.

En esta imagen lista los errores que aparecen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta otra se muestra donde esta el error, lo cual no entiendo por que esta pasando esto ya que yo no me e metido con estos archivos, alguien me podria dar solucion de que esta pasando.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: de casualidad habras compilado en Release en lugar de Debug ?

Comment: Quizas deberias ver quien activo el ESLint para evaluar estilo de codificacion para javascript  https://solidgeargroup.com/controla-estilo-codigo-de-equipo-eslint-javascript?lang=es

Comment: @LeandroTuttini no todo esta predeterminado incluso la forma de compilación, no a sido modificada

Comment: de casualidad no agregaste usando nuget o npm alguna libreria que pudiera habilitar ESLint ?

Answer (score 0):

No pasa nada, normalmente al cerrar el archivo se acaba el problema. Son errores del intelisense. Si miras el output verás que compila bien. En la imagen que te paso (lo tengo en ingles) selecciona solo compilación y verás cómo desaparecen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]